# Isometric Tiles Of Different Sizes Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, isometric

I am using Unity 5 to create an isometric game. I have generated a grid of tiles and it works well. However, when I use two different tiles to fill in the grid (their image sizes are slightly different), I get gaps in between the tiles. The obvious solution would be to create the tiles so that they are all the same image size, but this would prevent me from creating anything on a tile that is larger than the size of a tile (eg. a tree).

Here are some images to demonstrate:

With only one type of tile: [image]

With two types of tile: [image]

This is the code I use to create the map:

```
private void CreateMap() {

    float tileWidth;
    float tileHeight;

    int orderInLayer = 0;

    SpriteRenderer r = floorTiles [0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> (); 

    tileWidth = r.bounds.max.x - r.bounds.min.x;
    tileHeight = r.bounds.max.y - r.bounds.min.y;

    for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++) {
        orderInLayer += 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength (1); j++) {
            Vector2 position = new Vector2 ((j * tileWidth / 2) + (i * tileWidth / 2) + (tileWidth / 2), (j * tileHeight / 2) - (i * tileHeight / 2) + (tileHeight/ 2));
            r = map[i,j].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            r.sortingOrder = orderInLayer;
            Instantiate(map[i, j], position, Quaternion.identity);              

        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I cannot seem to fix it!

Comment: You could create a bit of an overlap. Another option is to stretch the smaller image.

Comment: Those two options could work, however that would make the map look strange, I'm looking for a perfect solution, the bad tiles just need adjusting slightly but I cannot find a way.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be calculating a position for each of your tiles from scratch every time you create one. If you have 2 different sized tiles, then your calculation comes out different, hence the gaps in your tiles. This is because you're only using the width/height of the current tile, failing to take into account any previous tiles that may be a shorter/longer height/width.

Given you have varying heights AND widths you'll need a way to calculate the correct position for both to prevent gaps in the X and Y direction. I've mocked up something here, but it's untested. More of a concept(?) I guess.

```
float tileHeight = 0;
float tileWidth = 0;

Vector2 position = new Vector2(0,0);

Dictionary<int, float> HeightMap = new Dictionary<int, float>();

for (int iRow = 0; iRow < map.GetLength(0); iRow++)
{
    position.x = 0;
    orderInLayer += 1;

    for (int jColumn = 0; jColumn < map.GetLength (1); jColumn++)
    {
        position.y = HeightMap[jColumn];

        r = map[iRow, jColumn].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        tileWidth = r.bounds.max.x - r.bounds.min.x;
        tileHeight = r.bounds.max.y - r.bounds.min.y;
        r.sortingOrder = orderInLayer;

        position.x += tileWidth / 2;

        position.y += tileHeight / 2;

        Instantiate(map[iRow, jColumn], position, Quaternion.identity);

        HeightMap[jColumn] = position.y;
    }
}
```

I leave the best way of storing the height, or instantiating the contents of the HeightMap dictionary to however you see fit.